Как объяснить временное значение предлога ПО в сочетании "по окончании чего-либо"?
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE

Временное значение предлога ПО выглядит как исключение. Обычно предлог ПО имеет направленное значение Д.п., например: судить (по чему? в соответствии с чем?) по ответу.

По окончании (П.п.) или по окончанию (Д. п.)? Такой вопрос задается часто, например в этой теме.


Ответ есть на портале Грамота.ру: По (с именем существительным в предложном падеже)
№ 319225. Во временно́м значении правильно по окончании (школы, недели и т. п.). Например: Нынче, по окончании смены, вызывают меня в кабинет самого Кресслинга.

А это пример употребления Д.п. со словом окончание: По окончанию существительного (по чему?) не всегда можно определить значение падежа.

Значение НАПРАВЛЕННОСТИ действия для предлога ПО в Д. п. более привычно современным пользователям языка, но как можно объяснить значение ВРЕМЕНИ в сочетаниях с этим предлогом в форме П.п.?  И всегда ли однозначно правильным был П.п., можно ли ожидать изменения ситуации?

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Ответы на эти вопросы можно найти в статье Изменение управления предлога по в русском языке.
Здесь же предлагаются некоторые тезисы из этой статьи.

Предлагаемое исследование посвящено изменению управления предлога ПО за последние два c половиной века. На протяжении рассматриваемого периода (с середины XVIII в. по настоящее время) предлог ПО имел вариативное управление: мог управлять как дательным, так и предложным падежом. К случаям такого вариативного употребления относится  временнóе значение ‘после’ (случилось по битве).

При этом во многих случаях конструкции по + предложный падеж и после + родительный падеж употреблялись как синонимичные в одинаковых контекстах: по отъезде — после отъезда, по первых волнениях — после первых волнений, по трудах — после трудов, по сих словах — после сих слов, по смерти — после
смерти, по князе — после князя и т. п.

Некоторые примеры:

Письма от тебя я жду, как жадный любовник, желающий видеть свою дражайшую по годовой отлучке. [А. Н. Радищев. М. Н. Радищеву (1797)]
По некоторых спорах защита почтена правильною. [А. Н. Радищев. Разрозненные заметки (1780–1802)]
Пусть по тоске и мраке дней / Они с покоем сладким, чистым / Почиют под холмом дернистым! [С. С. Бобров. Баллада. Могила Овидия, славного любимца муз (1792–1800)]
Но кроткая Екатерина, / Отрада по Петре едина, / Приемлет щедрой их рукой. [М. В. Ломоносов. Ода на день восшествия на всероссийский престол ее величества государыни императрицы Елисаветы Петровны (1747)]

В текстах XVIII в. мы находим такие употребления с предлогом ПО во временнóм значении, по которым нетрудно понять историю происхождения некоторых НАРЕЧИЙ (потом, пополудни, после):

По том в 1756 году был я в военное время послан за фуражем. [А. Н. Радищев. Офицерския упражнения (1773–1774)]
После чего крестьяне пошли, а я остался в коляске своей и, рассуждая о их состоянии, столь углубился в размышления, что не мог заснуть прежде двух часов по полуночи.[А. Н. Радищев. Отрывок путешествия (1772)]

В первой трети XIX в. рассматриваемая конструкция претерпевает существенные изменения, которые состоят в значительном ее сужении. Конструкция, в XVIII в. употреблявшаяся во всех речевых сферах, к концу первой трети XIX в. остается преимущественно в деловой и научной речи.  Сужение сферы распространения, грамматических форм и лексического состава связано прежде всего со все большим распространением конструкции после + род.п.

Предлог ПО начинает употребляться прежде всего с отглагольными существительными со значением действия: взятие, возвращение, вознесение, восшествие, вступление, выздоровление, выступление, заключение, занятие, изгнание, истечение, окончание, отбытие и др. Видимо, обширность этого списка связана прежде всего с большей регулярностью образования отглагольных существительных на -ие в XVIII–XIX вв., чем в современном языке

О конструкции Д. п. в значении после

Использование Д. п.  затухает в первые десятилетия XIX в. (вернулся по рассмотрению дел). Эти конструкции были мало употребительны уже в конце XVIII — начале XIX в.; в очень незначительном количестве они отмечаются у Пушкина: По окончанию трудов, Петр вынул карманную книжку, дабы справиться, всё ли им предполагаемое на сей день исполнено. [А. С. Пушкин. Арап Петра Великого (1828)]
К 50–60 годам XIX в. построения с дательным типа возвратился по усмирению совсем выходят из употребления. Что касается сочетаний ПО с отглагольными существительными на -ие, то в их числе можно выделить три группы: 1) затухающие — постепенно выходящие из употребления, 2) стабильные — сохраняющие высокую частотность на протяжении двух веков, 3) разгорающиеся — употребляющиеся со все возрастающей частотой. К затухающим сочетаниям рассматриваемого типа можно отнести по вступлении, по выступлении, по выздоровлении, по заключении, по миновании, по получении, по совершении; к стабильным — по возвращении, по окончании, по прибытии, по прочтении, по прошествии; к разгорающимся — по достижении, по завершении, по истечении.

С чем вообще связано ВАРИАНТНОЕ употребление Д. п. и П. п. в значении после?

Предлог ПО в дательном падеже близок к значению ‘на основании, согласно, в соответствии’,  причем в настоящее время сочетание по + дательный падеж получает все большее распространение и его значение расширяется. В разговорной речи замена предложного падежа на дательный в сочетаниях с предлогом по во временнóм значении происходит довольно часто.
Однако при всех возможных объяснениях этих отступлений от исходной конструкции по + предложный падеж, можно ли считать 3% употреблений, стабильно имеющихся на протяжении двух с половиной веков, вариативной нормой? Скорее нет, «они находятся если не за пределами, то в лучшем случае в серой зоне между нормой и ненормой»
ВЫВОД по материалам статьи: о значении "на основании, согласно, в соответствии"  для временного П. п
Можно ли увидеть направленное значение Д. п. в конструкциях с временным П. п.?
Рассмотрим предложение: Заполненный путевой лист по завершении (при завершении) поездки передается в отдел учета. Завершение/окончание поездки является основанием для закрытия путевого листа и передачи его в отдел учета.
По окончании колледжа многие выпускники поступают в вузы того же профиля. Здесь также окончание колледжа позволяет продолжить образование.
Таким образом, есть некоторое СБЛИЖЕНИЕ значений временного П.п. с направленным Д.п. Тем не менее Д. п. в этих конструкциях считается ненормированным, в частности из-за наличия парного варианта  с разными значениями: по окончании школы — определить по окончанию.
